# Generate word combination array in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string such as "big bad dog", how can I get an string[] array which includes all the possible word/phrase combinations?

So, I would like to return "big", "bad", "dog", "big bad", "bad dog" and "big bad dog" - therefore the order of the words in the original string must be respected.

Is this something that could be done with a regular expression?

Comment: What about "Big Dog"? as it still preserves the ordering, but ignores the middle word.

Comment: I've recently done a "bruteforce-like" routine that does exaclty that, but with letters. It doesn't use regular expressions, or i'd post it here

Comment: When you learn regex, everything looks like a nail...

Comment: Good point about "Big Dog" but no that should not count. I guess a better way of putting it is that I need all words/phrases that are consecutive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a nice problem to solve recursively. My take:

```
public static String[] findWords(params string[] args)
{

        if (args.Count() == 0)
        {
            return new String[] { "" };
        }
        else
        {
            String[] oldWords = findWords(args.Skip(1).ToArray());
            String[] newWords = oldWords.Where(word => word == "" || word.Split(new String[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0] == args[1])
                                        .Select(word => (args[0] + " " + word).Trim()).ToArray();

            return oldWords.Union(newWords).ToArray();
        }
}
```

A `findWords("big", "bad", "dog")` returns your list of phrases.

**Edit:** Edited to only include consecutive phrases.

Comment: This solves the problem but doesn't fully answer the OPs question.

Comment: Thanks Jens, this is pretty much what i wanted. Only one small problem (which i didn't explain in my original post) and that is I only want consecutive words or phrases so "big dog" should not be a match. Is there a tweak you can make to your code?

Comment: @Stuart: Edited. It looses elegance, though =)

Comment: Hi @Jen, that's great. Thanks a lot. Hopefully my gratitude will make up in some small way for the loss of elegance of your code! :)

Answer (score 6):

```
string[] array = new string[]{"big", "bad", "dog"};
for(ulong mask = 0; mask < (1ul << array.Length); mask++)
{
    string permutation = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < array.Length;  i++)
    {
        if((mask & (1ul << (array.Length - 1 - i))) != 0)
        {
            permutation += array[i] + " ";
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(permutation);
}
```

EDIT: No, it can not be done using only a single regular expression.

EDIT: Per Eric Lippert, change masks to ulong (UInt64).

Comment: This solves the problem but doesn't fully answer the OPs question.

Comment: And what if there are more than 32 words?  (I know, it'll take a while to get through the first four billion, but machines are fast these days.)

Answer (score 0):

What about splitting the string into array of separate words

```
string str = "big fat dog";
string[] words = str.Split(new Char[] { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' });
```

and then you can use this to make word combinations

> ```
> string[] words = new string[]{"big", "bad", "dog"}; 
> for(int mask = 0; mask < 1 << (words.Length); mask++) 
> { 
>   string permutation = ""; 
>   for(int i = 0; i < words.Length;  i++) 
>   { 
>     if((mask & (1 << (words.Length - 1 - i))) != 0) 
>     { 
>       permutation += words[i] + " "; 
>     } 
>   } 
>   Console.WriteLine(permutation); 
> }
> ```

I think regular expresion has no use here.

Comment: This solves the problem but doesn't fully answer the OPs question.