# Get all possible word combinations

Tags: c#, recursion, combinatorics, combinations

I have a list of n words (let's say 26). Now I want to get a list of all possible combinations, but with a maximum of k words per row (let's say 5)

So when my word list is: aaa, bbb, ..., zzz
I want to get:

```
aaa
bbb
...
aaabbb
aaaccc
...
aaabbbcccdddeeefff
aaabbbcccdddeeeggg
...
```

I want to make it variable, so that it will work with any n or k value.
There should be no word be twice and every combinations needs to be taken (even if there are very much).

How could I achieve that?

EDIT:

Thank you for your answers. It is not an assignment. Is is just that I forgot the combinations of my password and I want to be sure that I have all combinations tested. Although I have not 26 password parts, but this made it easier to explain what I want.

If there are other people with the same problem, this link could be helpfull:
[Generate word combination array in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401532/generate-word-combination-array-in-c)

Comment: You'll likely find the [Combinations template code from code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx) does what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx)

However, if you need to get large numbers of combinations (in the tens of millions) you should use lazy evaluation for the generation of the combinations.

Answer (score 3):

i wrote simple a function to do this

```
        private string allState(int index,string[] inStr)
        {
            string a = inStr[index].ToString();
            int l = index+1;
            int k = l;
            var result = string.Empty;
            var t = inStr.Length;
            int i = index;
            while (i < t)
            {
                string s = a;
                for (int j = l; j < k; j++)
                {
                    s += inStr[j].ToString();
                }
                result += s+",";
                k++;
                i++;
            }

            index++;
            if(index<inStr.Length)
                result += allState(index, inStr);
            return result.TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' });
        }

allState(0, new string[] { "a", "b", "c"})
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only works for lists of 3 strings.  Anything bigger and it starts missing combinations.  IE: ABCD will give you ABCD, ABC, BCD but it doesn't give ACD