# How to generate passwords?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get all possible word combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290889/get-all-possible-word-combinations)

I have a string `"abcdefgklmno0123456789"`

I need to enumerate all the possible combinations with sizes ranging from 6 to 7 characters.

`aaaaaa aaaaab aaaaac ... 999999`

Comment: "I need to enumerate all the possible combinations " - No, you don't. Not if you are generating passwords...More like trying to break passwords...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, you do if you're trying to crack them. I think there must be a school out there that's set this as part of an assignment.

Comment: It's a shame no one uses "p" in their passwords these days. :(

Comment: Or any character after 'p', or 'h','i','j' either.

Comment: my favorite password is 'password123'

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: That's the combination on my luggage!

Answer (score 3):

You could use Linq to do it:

```
string s = "abcdefgklmno0123456789";

var pwdWith6Chars =
            from a in s
            from b in s
            from c in s
            from d in s
            from e in s
            from f in s
            select new string(new[] { a, b, c, d, e, f });

var pwdWith7Chars =
            from a in s
            from b in s
            from c in s
            from d in s
            from e in s
            from f in s
            from g in s
            select new string(new[] { a, b, c, d, e, f, g });

var passwords = pwdWith6Chars.Concat(pwdWith7Chars).ToList();
```

Comment: It's just a Cartesian product... there's a way to generalize it, see [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Please check out following link.

It will help you

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use a recursion to generate this list.

Pseudocode (more like C):

```
str = "abcdefgklmno0123456789"
res = empty string of 6 letters
results = list of string

function go(level) {
  if (level == 6 or level == 7) {
    add "res" to "results" list
    if (level == 7) {
      return
    }
  }
  for(i=position; i<len(str); i++) {
    res[level] = str[i]
    go(level+1)
  }
}
```

Then, you just call go(0).

Instead of use a result list, you could also use yield operator to create an iterator.
Iterator has the advantage to save memory, because you will be yielding each combination instead of storing all of them.