# How to get powered list of a string in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get all possible word combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290889/get-all-possible-word-combinations)

I want to get a "power list" of a string.  So given this input:

```
string[] s = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" } ;
```

The function would return:

```
string[] s = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "ab", "ac", "bc", "abc" } ;
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: This is just a get all combinations question...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290889/get-all-possible-word-combinations

Comment: If the output gives the empty string as well it will probably compose more nicely with whatever you are using it in.  More consistent.

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401532/generate-word-combination-array-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
string[] chars = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };

List<string> result = new List<string>();
foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, 4))
{
    IEnumerable<string> coll = chars;
    foreach (int j in Enumerable.Range(0, i))
    {
        coll = coll.SelectMany(s => chars, (c, r) => c + r);
    }
    result.AddRange(coll);
}
```

Comment: it return 120 string , I only need that 6 string , try yourself